# Creating and using a variable in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

The edited out code works when I test it to print the variable, but it's useless this way. I want to *use* the user entered information as a variable to open a file. When done like this, the FileName variable is empty. What can I do here?

```
def menu3A():
    variable1= StringVar()
    ttk.Entry(root, width=7, textvariable=variable1).grid(column=2, row=1)

    ttk.Label(root, text="Enter Filename: ").grid(column=1, row=1)

    #ttk.Button(root, text="Enter", command= lambda: print(f"This is {variable1.get()}")).grid(column=2, row=13)
    ttk.Button(root, text="Enter", command= lambda FileName=variable1.get(): finance.CSV_Finance_Tool(FileName)).grid(column=2, row=13)
```

Comment: In fact you don't need the default valued parameter at all, just `command=lambda: finance.CSV_Finance_Tool(FileName.get())`. At the moment you're binding the _initial_ value, which is empty.

Comment: you are my new favorite person. That worked! Thank you Thank you Thank you!

Comment: Please, either you or @jonrsharpe, post an answer to this question, so that others know that it has been answered satisfactorily.

Comment: @jonrsharpe when I try to send two arguments, it doesn't work. Do you know why?: command = lambda : finance.Finance_Tool(FileName, TimeFrame.get())

Comment: I don't know, does that method accept two arguments? What's the error? I'd note that you're only calling get on one, are they both StringVars?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It works for filename. The previous function has the user enter the filename and that works beautifully. This function has the user enter a time period. Then it sends both of the arguments to a function that takes this and graphs it out using yfinance. The timeframe is printing as a blank, but the file is printing aapl (what I am entering as the user). So it works fine with one argument, but it isn't working once I try to send 2 arguments.

Comment: @jonrsharpe and there isn't any error. I have it print out each argument to make sure they are coming over correctly and time is coming up: "Time frame entered is: ". My graph still prints because I have it set that if there are no variables set that it automatically chooses to print 1 day.

Comment: "Isn't working" isn't enough to go on. See [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe never mind thank you so much for all your help. I fixed it! I never changed the name on one of the spots for the variable. ‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

Solution from comments:

> In fact you don't need the default valued parameter at all, just `command=lambda: finance.CSV_Finance_Tool(FileName.get())`. At the moment you're binding the initial value, which is empty.

This answered the question. Thanks to [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)!